# Adding current scene to VSE (Blender 2.8)

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I dont know why this isn't working. I'm so new to Blender so forgive me.

I'm trying to reverse my animation:
https://youtu.be/jhXfWWeGVQg?t=333

I've got it all set up, I go into the `Video Sequencer` and I right click:
[image]

And this is what I get.  Why can't I add it? He does it in the video okay.

Answer (score 4):

You can't add the current scene. Just Add a new Scene to the file and use the VSE from there now you can add the *other* Scene.

Answer (score 2):

The man in the tutorial is not using 2.8. The manual for 2.8 says:

> #### Scene Strip
>
> Scene strips are a way to insert the render output of **another** scene into your sequence(...)

It looks like you need to save your scene as a .blend file **first** and then add it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add all scenes, you can create a new empty scene and select it in 'Outliner' panel(choose scene), then turn to "video editing -sequencer-add -scene", you can see all scenes except the empty one.